# Trying to download from github to linux but their is only zip and gz

Tags: linux, git, github

trying to download an older version of PhoneInfoga to linux.
i can't because i don't know how to download zip to linux here's the link
https://github.com/sundowndev/PhoneInfoga/releases/tag/v1.10.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several releases of PhoneInfoga for Linux, depending on your platform. They're all `tar.gz` files, which can be extracted with

```
$ tar -xf filename.tar.gz
```

replacing `filename` with the name of the file you downloaded.

Comment: that just keeps giving me error "no such file or directory" even after using the path as well. the tar.gz folder is in downloads

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same directory as the file? If you run `ls` does your file appear? Also, could you paste the command that you're using here?